# How to use disableNativeAutomation in TestCafe for one test only?

Tags: testcafe

Native Automation Mode doesn't support multiple windows.
I have two tests.
One of them uses multiple windows.

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction, t } from 'testcafe';
fixture('two tests')
    .page(process.env.SITE_URL)

    test('test1', async t => {
         // usual test
    })
    test('test1', async t => {
         // test uses multiple windows
    })
```

How to disable Native Automation in TestCafe for test2 only?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two separate test runs - in Native Automation mode and without it. Specify test paths with the glob pattern as follows: [Test files](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#test-files). Use [the](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--disable-native-automation) [`--disable-native-automation`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--disable-native-automation) option for this purpose.

Run tests with NA:

```
testcafe chrome "tests/**/*" "!tests/multiple-tests/**/*"
```

Run tests without NA:

```
testcafe chrome "tests/multiple-tests/**/*" --disable-native-automation
```

You can do the same with [configuration files](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file) or with a [Runner](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402641/reference/testcafe-api/runner) object. Also, you can filter tests by [metadata](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#filter-tests-and-fixtures-by-name-grep-pattern-or-metadata).